# Can you please help me running beef-xss with public IP?

Tags: ip, kali-linux

I have problem with running beef-xss with my public IP address.

##### here is my config.yaml:

```
#Copyright (c) 2006-2024 Wade Alcorn - wade@bindshell.net
#Browser Exploitation Framework (BeEF) - https://beefproject.com
#See the file 'doc/COPYING' for copying permission
#BeEF Configuration file

beef:
    version: '0.5.4.0'
    # More verbose messages (server-side)
    debug: false
    # More verbose messages (client-side)
    client_debug: true
    # Used for generating secure tokens
    crypto_default_value_length: 80

    # Credentials to authenticate in BeEF.
    # Used by both the RESTful API and the Admin interface
    credentials:
        user:   "beef"
        passwd: "hreoz"

    # Interface / IP restrictions
    restrictions:
        # subnet of IP addresses that can hook to the framework
        permitted_hooking_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
        # subnet of IP addresses that can connect to the admin UI
        #permitted_ui_subnet: ["127.0.0.1/32", "::1/128"]
        permitted_ui_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
        # subnet of IP addresses that cannot be hooked by the framework
        excluded_hooking_subnet: []
        # slow API calls to 1 every  api_attempt_delay  seconds
        api_attempt_delay: "0.05"

    # HTTP server 
    http:
        debug: false #Thin::Logging.debug, very verbose. Prints also full exception stack trace.
        host: "0.0.0.0"
        port: "4444"

        # Decrease this setting to 1,000 (ms) if you want more responsiveness
        #  when sending modules and retrieving results.
        # NOTE: A poll timeout of less than 5,000 (ms) might impact performance
        #  when hooking lots of browsers (50+).
        # Enabling WebSockets is generally better (beef.websocket.enable)
        xhr_poll_timeout: 1000

        # Public Domain Name / Reverse Proxy / Port Forwarding
        #
        # In order for the client-side BeEF JavaScript hook to be able to connect to BeEF,
        # the hook JavaScript needs to be generated with the correct connect-back details.
        #
        # If you're using a public domain name, reverse proxy, or port forwarding you must
        # configure the public-facing connection details here.

        public:
            host: "41.98.71.13" # public hostname/IP address
            port: "4444" # public port (443 if the public server is using HTTPS)
            https: true # true/false

        # If using any reverse proxy you should also set allow_reverse_proxy to true below.
        # Note that this causes the BeEF server to trust the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header.
        # If the BeEF server is directly accessible, clients can spoof their connecting
        # IP address using this header to bypass the IP address permissions/exclusions.
        allow_reverse_proxy: false

        # Hook
        hook_file: "/hook.js"
        hook_session_name: "BEEFHOOK"

        # Allow one or multiple origins to access the RESTful API using CORS
        # For multiple origins use: "http://browserhacker.com, http://domain2.com"
        restful_api:
            allow_cors: false
            cors_allowed_domains: "http://browserhacker.com"

        # Prefer WebSockets over XHR-polling when possible.
        websocket:
            enable: false
            port: 61985 # WS: good success rate through proxies
            # Use encrypted 'WebSocketSecure'
            # NOTE: works only on HTTPS domains and with HTTPS support enabled in BeEF
            secure: true
            secure_port: 61986 # WSSecure
            ws_poll_timeout: 5000 # poll BeEF every x second, this affects how often the browser can have a command execute on it
            ws_connect_timeout: 500 # useful to help fingerprinting finish before establishing the WS channel

        # Imitate a specified web server (default root page, 404 default error page, 'Server' HTTP response header)
        web_server_imitation:
            enable: true
            type: "apache" # Supported: apache, iis, nginx
            hook_404: false # inject BeEF hook in HTTP 404 responses
            hook_root: false # inject BeEF hook in the server home page
        # Experimental HTTPS support for the hook / admin / all other Thin managed web services
        https:
            enable: false
            # In production environments, be sure to use a valid certificate signed for the value
            # used in beef.http.public (the domain name of the server where you run BeEF)
            key: "beef_key.pem"
            cert: "beef_cert.pem"

    database:
        file: "beef.db"

    # Autorun Rule Engine
    autorun:
        # this is used when rule chain_mode type is nested-forward, needed as command results are checked via setInterval
        # to ensure that we can wait for async command results. The timeout is needed to prevent infinite loops or eventually
        # continue execution regardless of results.
        # If you're chaining multiple async modules, and you expect them to complete in more than 5 seconds, increase the timeout.
        result_poll_interval: 300
        result_poll_timeout: 5000

        # If the modules doesn't return status/results and timeout exceeded, continue anyway with the chain.
        # This is useful to call modules (nested-forward chain mode) that are not returning their status/results.
        continue_after_timeout: true

    # Enables DNS lookups on zombie IP addresses
    dns_hostname_lookup: false

    # IP Geolocation
    geoip:
        enable: true
        # GeoLite2 City database created by MaxMind, available from https://www.maxmind.com
        database: '/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'

    # You may override default extension configuration parameters here
    # Note: additional experimental extensions are available in the 'extensions' directory
    #       and can be enabled via their respective 'config.yaml' file
    extension:
        admin_ui:
            enable: true
            base_path: "/ui"
        demos:
            enable: true
        events:
            enable: true
        evasion:
            enable: false
        requester:
            enable: true
        proxy:
            enable: true
        network:
            enable: true
        metasploit:
            enable: false
        social_engineering:
            enable: false
        xssrays:
            enable: true
```

##### here is my iptables forwarding :

```
# sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https       to:192.168.1.14:443
2    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4444 to:192.168.1.14:4444
3    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql to:192.168.1.14:5432
4    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:55552 to:192.168.1.14:55552
5    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3001 to:192.168.1.14:3000
6    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:192.168.1.14:8080
7    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp to:192.168.1.14:2121
```

##### router forwarding:

router forwarding is the same

##### terminal :

[image: beef-xss logs]

Can you please help me running beef-xss with public IP. What seems to be problem here?

Comment: It appears the service is running? What’s your problem?

Comment: the problem that I cant access it from public ip the service it running but it says " unable to connect "

Comment: Did you forward the port? Your service is configured to work on your current public IP address. It likely will NOt work within your own network though